# Exporting firefox passwords, form fields and cookie information to new machine

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I am about to travel, and I will be using a new laptop (to be purchased in the next day or two) for all my work during my travels. I have a lot of information stored in my firefox browser (e.g. passwords, form inputs etc), which makes my life easy.

I need to export all the data in my firefox, so that I can import it for use with firefox on my new laptop. Ideally, I want to be able to export the data into a text file and then import into firefox on my laptop.

Does anyone know how I may export/import my personal data from/into firefox?

As an aside, my desktop OS is Ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS and it is very likely that my new laptop will be running Ubuntu too.

Comment: Just copy the profile folder and place it on a flash drive.  Then migrate the profile folder to the correct location on the new computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Firefox addon Password Exporter

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/password-exporter/

You can import/export passwords.

## Firefox Sync

Firefox Sync is a secure way to exchange bookmarks/passwords/history/etc between two computers through the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the Firefox sync method, however if your trying to locate the file in which they are stored on Ubuntu then:

"you can copy " .mozilla" file as backup, in case you reinstall the system.

file is hidden in home folder and can be viewed by selecting ' show hidden files ' from nautilus menu. you have to copy it in the same location after system reinstall" - http://tinyurl.com/passwordsmozilla

Answer (score 0):

As @Ramhound stated, the easiest and most direct way to copy all data from one Firefox profile to another is by copying the profile folder to a flash drive and form it copying it to the new laptop.

On Linux, the profile folder is located at:

```
~/.mozilla/firefox/<profile folder>
```

<sub>([source](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox#Linux))([source](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data))</sub>

The profile folder is, in most cases, a single folder with a randoname.default kind of format. That is what your profile is. You might also find in the firefox/ folder a .ini file called `profiles.ini` that contains the path information for your profile. The following is an example:

```
[General]
StartWithLastProfile=1

[Profile0]
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=yourprofilename.default
Default=1
```

Copy it to a flash drive and in the other installation, just paste it. Remember to alter the `profiles.ini` to match your profile.

In alternative, just run Firefox in the following way:

```
./firefox -profilemanager
```

<sub>([source](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_Manager#Linux))</sub>

This will take you to the Profile Manager, where you can then select your old profile.